# Is there a way to select a certain part of an HTML file and paste it in another file using python?

Tags: python, html, automation

This is a relatively simple question, but I cannot find a way to do this using python. I'm trying to select a certain part of each HTML file in my database, and paste it in another file. Is there a way to do at least the first part, and, if possible, the second part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could probably look into web scraping even if it's local files it could grab data from HTML. If you do plan on scraping them look into BeautifulSoup4. As for the second part I personally haven't looked into that so maybe others can shine some light.

Comment: That would be a great solution, but I am trying to copy a div tag, and BeautifulSoup4 seems to only copy head and body tags.

Comment: BeautifulSoup4 can most definitely access div tags. Once you create a soup you can use code like this "soup.find("div", {"id": "articlebody"})" to find divs, or also divs with specific id's

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Does the same thing work for div classes?

Comment: it sure does, just change "id" to "class"